# why build showing errors in cominterfaces.tlh

Tags: c++, c++17

Any clue will be great , since I am totally no clue in C++ code.
I am getting following error while building the project

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   \releasemindependency\cominterfaces.tlh 592

Line number in cominterfaces.tlh

```
*

*IVoxarClinAppBuilder* : *IUnknown*
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall Initialise (
        /*[in]*/ struct IVoxarFeatureAvailability * feature_availability,
        /*[in]*/ struct IVoxarImport * voxar_import,
        /*[in]*/ struct IVoxarExport * export,
        /*[in]*/ struct IVoxarSettingsNode * settings,
        /*[in]*/ struct IVoxarClinAppEvents * events,
        /*[out]*/ struct IVoxarClinApp * * clin_app,
        /*[out]*/ struct IPvMethodResult * * method_result00 ) = 0;
};
```

- 

[image]

Comment: All the relevant code should be pasted as text into the question body. Screenshots, or other images are not readable at all.

Comment: What is a '.tlh' file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well seems like all the arrows points out '[export](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/export)' which I just found it to be a C++ keyword. But seems like it wanted to be use as a variable name there. Maybe changing 'export' to 'voxar_export' might help. Just like 'voxar_import' line above it. But it is just a guessy solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kao! it really helped.

Comment: Glad it helped. Unlike javascript `export` is not a popular keyword in C++. I'm writing C++ for years. But I never saw anyone use it before. So your question just taught me not to use it as a variable or function name. Thank you too.